# Checking a userform has been saved with save_click before closing

Tags: excel, vba, save, userform

I am very new to VBA and have created a userform for colleagues to input data that is then saved to a worksheet. I have save button, a new record button, and a close button. Save does what it says on the tin, new record clears the form and close closes it. All pretty straightforward. However, I would like to be able to add a function to check if the form has been saved when the 'close' has been clicked, which then gives a pop up with "This record has not been saved, do you wish to save now or close without saving" and two options to choose from, 'save and close' or 'close without saving'.

Is this possible? I have searched and searched and cant find the answer! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Define a boolean var (eg "dataIsSaved") in your form

- set it to `false` when data is changed (or whenever you think that a
  save would be needed),
- set it to `true` when the data is saved
- check it when the close button is pressed.

Comment: Thank you for the response, how would this be set out in code please? As I said, I am very new to VBA!